# Clicking to load new edits doesn't load the new automated duplicate box

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, duplicate-questions, live-refresh

When someone has voted to close the question as a duplicate, then someone makes an edit to the question, the new automated duplicate box does not get loaded with the edit. If it was already there, it actually gets *removed* until you reload the page to insert it again.

The box should be included as part of the post when loading new edits. As well, it would be nice that any changes to the duplicate box (first added, changed to add new links, or removed) would also be pushed as an "edit" (at least for the sake of updating the post via live-refresh), even though it's not an actual "revision" on the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When live-refreshing edits on closed-as-duplicate questions, the refresh will now include the duplicates banner.

Live-refreshing a state change (e.g. closure, deletion) isn't currently supported, but it's something we'd like to add.