# The "migrated from..." banner disappears if you click on that yellow box that shows up when a post is edited

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, live-refresh

When you're looking at a question that has a "migrated from..." banner (like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232228/224428)), and then somebody edits a post, spawns one of those yellow boxes that prompt you to click to reload that post, and you click on that box, the "migrated from..." banner vanishes.

This bug appears to have been fixed for other types of banners (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167204/224428)).